# Python kills all parent process when there is an error in multiprocessing

Tags: python, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a cron-script that calls two scripts let say A.sh and B.sh. Script A calls a python file Run_Multirocessing.py here we have task in which we have to search some columns using name in dataframe and remove some values. We are doing it using multiprocessing. We divide the df into parts and call function using parallel processing

```
for i in range(0, cores):
    proc = Process(target=removalDF, args=(outDf[i], ruleFolder, caseFolder, clientName, out_q, i))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()
    logInfo('Processing '+str(i)+'...', 'track')
outDf = out_q.get()
for i in range(1, cores):
    outDf = outDf.append(out_q.get(), ignore_index=True)
for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

but whenever there is an error in removalDF it kills all process and all scripts. Code stuck

Comment: have you tried catching the exception in a `try .. except` block?

Comment: I deleted the `processing` tag. That tag is for the programming language called "Processing" and has nothing to do with your question. Please read the description of a tag before deciding to use it.

Comment: @SudhirTiwari "Processing" is an awful name for a language, so it is a completely understandable error to assume that it is a more general tag.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel yes i tried but it didn't work

Comment: if there's an exception in `removalIDK` it should just stop this one process but not the other `removalIDK` processes and especially not the `B` script. I plainly not believe that this can be the case :) can you prove it with e.g. pasting a shell session. Best would be if `processIDK` prints output every second and also script `B` sends output periodically so you can prove that it really died. `ps aux` output is also helpful